# Find share sizes across multiple servers -powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, network-share

I have about 1600 old home drives that I need to capture the folder sizes on.  They are spread across 12 NAS Appliances and I need to get the size of each folder.  I see this asked a lot but they are always asking  for all the shares on a single server.

I have used simple one-liners like the the one below which work great.

```
Get-ChildItem \\Server1\Users\User1 -file -recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length
```

How can I feed in a txt or csv from multiple locations?

Like

```
\\Server1\Users\User1
\\Server2\Users\User1
\\Server3\Users\User1
\\Server4\Users\User1
\\Server5\Users\User1
\\Server6\Users\User1
\\Server7\Users\User1
etc...
```

Exporting to a csv would be nice as well.

thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Get-Content` to read your text file line-by-line:

```
Get-Content .\path\to\file.txt
```

Next up we need to repeat your one-liner for each line:

```
Get-Content .\path\to\file.txt |ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem $_ -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length
}
```

This will give us 1600 individual measurements - but now we won't know which paths they belong to...

To track which measurement belongs to which user directory, let's create a new object containing both all the information instead:

```
Get-Content .\path\to\file.txt |ForEach-Object {
  $Measurement = Get-ChildItem $_ -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Path = $_
    FileCount = $Measurement.Count
    TotalSize = $Measurement.Sum
  }
}
```

Finally, we can export to CSV using `Export-Csv`:

```
Get-Content .\path\to\file.txt |ForEach-Object {
  $Measurement = Get-ChildItem $_ -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Path = $_
    FileCount = $Measurement.Count
    TotalSize = $Measurement.Sum
  }
} |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much!  Works perfectly.